# frame-benchmarking version conflict

Tags: rust

Below is the cargo.toml file of one of my pallet.

```
[package]
name = "escrow"
version = "3.0.0"
edition = "2018"
authors = ['Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>']
repository = 'https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/recipes'
description = "A pallet that demonstrates storing custom structs in Substrate storage"
license = "GPL-3.0-or-later"

[dependencies]
parity-scale-codec = { version = "2.0", features = ["derive"], default-features = false }

#Optional imports for benchmarking
frame-benchmarking = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", default-features = false, optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v0.9.16" }

# Substrate packages
pallet-balances = { version = '3.0', default-features = false }
frame-support = { version = '3.0', default-features = false }
frame-system = { version = '3.0', default-features = false }
sp-runtime = { version = '3.0', default-features = false }

[dev-dependencies]
serde = '1.0'
sp-core = '3.0'
sp-io = '3.0'

[features]
default = ['std']
std = [
    'pallet-balances/std',
    'frame-support/std',
    'frame-system/std',
    'parity-scale-codec/std',
    'sp-runtime/std',
]
```

After I added the :

```
#Optional imports for benchmarking
frame-benchmarking = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", default-features = false, optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v0.9.16" }
```

I am having the below error:

```
stdout :     Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate`
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`.
    ... required by package `sp-runtime v4.1.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.16#19162e43)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sp-runtime` of package `frame-benchmarking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.16#19162e43)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking` of package `escrow v3.0.0 (/Users/elioprifti/recipes/pallets/escrow)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `escrow` (locked to 3.0.0) of package `super-runtime v3.0.0 (/Users/elioprifti/recipes/runtimes/super-runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `runtime` (locked to 3.0.0) of package `basic-pow v3.0.0 (/Users/elioprifti/recipes/nodes/basic-pow)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.10.2` are: 0.10.2

the package `parity-util-mem` links to the native library `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates` as well:
package `parity-util-mem v0.9.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `parity-util-mem = "^0.9.0"` (locked to 0.9.0) of package `sc-service v0.9.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sc-service = "^0.9"` (locked to 0.9.0) of package `basic-pow v3.0.0 (/Users/elioprifti/recipes/nodes/basic-pow)`
Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the links ='parity-util-mem' value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.

failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem` which could resolve this conflict

stderr :
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the `polkadot-v0.9.x` to all your Substrate dependencies.

Take a look here:

- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/6a8b2b12371395979099d2c79ccc1860531b0449/runtime/Cargo.toml#L47

Notice how **all** the Substrate dependencies have `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28"`

Same goes for the pallet:

```
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, optional = true, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }

[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }
sp-io = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }
sp-runtime = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }
```

- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/6a8b2b12371395979099d2c79ccc1860531b0449/pallets/template/Cargo.toml#L20-L27

Comment: It still does not work :/

Comment: Create a reproducible example, push it up to Github, and share it on here - otherwise there isn't much I can do without guessing what it could be.

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/herou/recipes/tree/only-escrow Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not building this pallet on [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template)? [Substrate Recipes](https://github.com/JoshOrndorff/recipes) is quite out-dated. It is fine for studying but I would recommend building your pallet on [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I really appreciate it.
Trying to build the substrate-node-template I get this issue:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4591/mac-m1-substrate-node-template-cant-be-build
Can you please help me?