# Mac m1 substrate node template can't be build

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I get this issue when I try to build the substrate-node-template

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `prost-build v0.10.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/elioprifti/substrate-node-template/target/debug/build/prost-build-842a283f6884a648/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=/Users/elioprifti/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/prost-build-0.10.4/third-party/protobuf/cmake
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CMAKE_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CMAKE = None
  CMAKE = None
  running: "cmake" "/Users/elioprifti/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/prost-build-0.10.4/third-party/protobuf/cmake" "-Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/elioprifti/substrate-node-template/target/debug/build/prost-build-ff54cba47a5a17d8/out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -arch arm64" "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -arch arm64" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -arch arm64" "-DCMAKE_ASM_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  failed to execute command: No such file or directory (os error 2)
  is `cmake` not installed?

  build script failed, must exit now', /Users/elioprifti/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cmake-0.1.48/src/lib.rs:975:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
elioprifti@pc-193-62 substrate-node-template %
```

Rust configuration:

```
elioprifti@pc-193-62 ~ % rustup show                                
rustup +nightly show

Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/elioprifti/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)

Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/elioprifti/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.65.0-nightly (2e35f954a 2022-09-01)

elioprifti@pc-193-62 ~ %
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The error is pointing this out:

```
is `cmake` not installed?
```

Comment: Yes, 'cmake' is installed

Answer (score 1):

Always restart your machine, this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not finding it.

```sh
brew update
brew uninstall cmake
brew install cmake
```

Make sure it is installed:

```
cmake --help
```

Make sure you follow the steps here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/install/macos/#install-required-packages-and-rust

Comment: I followed the steps above.

elioprifti@pc-193-62 ~ % cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
elioprifti@pc-193-62 ~ %

Comment: I am running the same version on an M1 and [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/releases/tag/polkadot-v0.9.28) builds fine.

Comment: I had to restart my pc to fix it. Thank you!